# One line doesn't show up but the others do

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a graph of two variables, with facet_grid. This is the graph I have at the moment:

[My graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ej5lY.png)

This is almost what I want, except that there is no line for "SURFACE" in the "Changed" facet and I can't work out why.

This is my data:

```
    data <- read.table(text = "
   lag.distance mantel.statistic       Sig      WM
1       0.00000       0.44755550   Changed SURFACE
2      36.66667       0.57002150   Changed SURFACE
3      95.00000      -0.40571540   Changed SURFACE
4     203.33333       0.10481760   Changed SURFACE
5     292.50000      -0.48685840   Changed SURFACE
6       0.00000       0.44755550   Changed    DEEP
7      36.66667       0.57002150   Changed    DEEP
8      95.00000      -0.40571540   Changed    DEEP
9     203.33333       0.10481760   Changed    DEEP
10    292.50000      -0.48685840   Changed    DEEP
11      0.00000       0.46796510 Conserved SURFACE
12     36.66667       0.53094700 Conserved SURFACE
13     95.00000      -0.38027290 Conserved SURFACE
14    203.33333      -0.61828110 Conserved SURFACE
15    292.50000       0.21224900 Conserved SURFACE
16      0.00000       0.20225996 Conserved    DEEP
17     34.00000      -0.08036996 Conserved    DEEP
18     81.00000      -0.04005344 Conserved    DEEP
19    202.25000       0.09716254 Conserved    DEEP
20    280.00000      -0.20026720 Conserved    DEEP
    ", header = TRUE)
```

This is my code:

```
data$WM <- factor(data$WM, levels = c("SURFACE", "DEEP"))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x=lag.distance,y=mantel.statistic,color=WM)) + geom_line(size=1) + geom_point(size=3) +
  labs(colour="Depth", x = "Lag distance (days)", y = "Mantel statistic")+
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "lightgray"),
        panel.background = element_blank())+ 
  theme(strip.background = element_blank())+
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, color = "lightgray")+
  facet_grid(Sig~.)
```

As you can see, my data contains values for "SURFACE" for "Changed", so why are these not plotted?

Comment: your values for `mantel.statistic` for `SURFACE` and `DEEP` (where `Sig == "changed"`) are exactly the same

Comment: So there is a line there, it's just 'hidden' beneth the other one.

Comment: Oh wow, I'm stupid. Thanks!

Comment: ;-) - also, your `panel.border = ...` line hides all the lines in my plots (using `ggplot2 v2.0.0` )